# javac not displaying compiler errors?

Tags: java, windows, compiler-errors, javac

I'm teaching my friend some Java, and we're running into issues trying to run the compiler on her Hello World program. The code had a pretty glaring error (`Sysrem.out.println`), but otherwise was totally valid Java, but for some reason the compiler didn't report the error. Here's what happened:

1. When we ran `javac Hello.java` in Windows Command Prompt, it printed out a blank line and then a new command prompt line, as if the operation had succeeded, but it clearly hadn't - a class file wasn't created, and of course the code had an error so we knew it wouldn't be successful.
2. When we ran `javac -verbose Hello.java`, it printed out the gory details of the class files it was loading, but then that was it. While it didn't end by saying it had written a class file, it also didn't print out the error.
3. After we fixed the error, the program compiled and ran without a problem, so it seems to be that javac just doesn't like printing out compiler errors.

What could be going on here, why isn't the compiler reporting this error like it should?

The complete code:

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sysrem.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

The command prompt:

```
C:\Users\MyFriendsName\Documents>javac Hello.java

C:\Users\MyFriendsName\Documents>
```

Comment: show the code..

Comment: Sysrem should be System.

Comment: @ShanuGupta Just added the code. I know what the issue in the code is, what I don't know is why the compiler isn't printing out the error like it should.

Comment: Your complete code looks fine, you didn't use `Sysrem` in it. Javac was simply compiling it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, that was my bad when entering it here. `Sysrem` was very much present when we tried to use it.

Comment: Edited to fix it. When we gave that to javac, it failed to create a compiled file but also didn't spit out an error.

Comment: @user24601 is it consistent or intermittent?

Comment: @ShanuGupta It's consistent, we ran javac multiple times with the same result, just a blank line.

Comment: Can someone with a Window JDK installation please try to reproduce this behavior?  I'm finding it hard to believe that a `javac` would do this ... unless you did something to redirected or suppress the compilation error messages.

Comment: @user24601 Did you saved the file with sysrem?

Comment: @StephenC We didn't do anything beyond the basic setup. Installed JDK 1.8.0_171, put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;` at the start of PATH, then called `javac`.

Comment: Well ... this is why I am asking for someone else to please reproduce the behavior.  (I can't because I don't have a Windows machine.   And I >>do<< get compilation errors on my Linux install of jdk1.8.0_171)

Comment: @StephenC Now, given the self answer by the user, that the file was actually unsaved and empty ... I am more wondering: should this be closed as typo, or is it good to go ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What this actually boils down to is whether an empty file is a valid Java program.  Surprisingly, it is!

Here is the grammar for a `CompilationUnit` ... which is the technical term that that JLS uses for a Java source file:

```
CompilationUnit:
   OrdinaryCompilationUnit
   ModularCompilationUnit

OrdinaryCompilationUnit:
   [PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}

ModularCompilationUnit:
   {ImportDeclaration} ModuleDeclaration
```

(Reference: [JLS 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3))

Note that the `OrdinaryCompilationUnit` element allows you to have a source file that consists of:

- no package statement
- no import statements
- no type declarations

In other words, an empty file, or a file that just contains comments.

In short, if you tell `javac` to compile an empty file, it won't produce any compilation errors ... because it is "valid" Java source code file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered the issue: Turns out my friend had never hit Save on her file after creating it, and in what I'm assuming is just some unintuitively-designed expected behavior, **javac doesn't complain about being fed a blank file!**

Here's exactly what happened:

- Create the file
- Write the buggy code but don't save the file
- Attempt to compile the code and hit the issue described in my question
- Correct the bug in the code and save the file
- Compile and run the code without a problem

Comment: You might want to add that maybe a "good" practice is then to use something like `type Hello.java` on the command line (or `cat Hello.java` on Linux) to ensure that the file really has the expected content.